# Not able to change the background color of the bs4Dash::dashboardSidebar() properly

Tags: css, r, shiny, bs4dash

**1. Color issue using only the *bs4Dash* package**

I am starting to use the package *bs4Dash* and I am facing a problem with the background color of the left sidebar bs4Dash::dashboardSidebar(). I observe that when I start the app the background color of the left sidebar is always in gray, but when I switch to dark mode and back to light mode the color render with a white color background.

You can observe this behavior using the code below that was taken from [help webpage](https://rinterface.github.io/bs4Dash/articles/step-by-step.html) of *bs4Dash*

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

shinyApp(
    ui = dashboardPage(
        title = "Basic Dashboard",
        header = dashboardHeader(),
        sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
        controlbar = dashboardControlbar(),
        footer = dashboardFooter(),
        body = dashboardBody()
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

**2. Color problem using *fresh* and *bs4Dash* package**

Using the package *fresh* when I open the app for the first time It is still with the grey background color, but when I switch from dark mode to light It renders the color according to fresh::create_theme().

Here is an example

```
# library

library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(fresh)

# theme creator with fresh::

mytheme <- create_theme(
    bs4dash_sidebar_light(
        bg = "#FFFF00")
)

#shinyApp

shinyApp(
    ui = dashboardPage(
        title = "Basic Dashboard",
        header = dashboardHeader(),
        sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
        controlbar = dashboardControlbar(),
        footer = dashboardFooter(),
        body = dashboardBody(use_theme(mytheme)),
        freshTheme = TRUE
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

I found out [this](https://github.com/RinteRface/bs4Dash/issues/168) issue in the Github but can't figure out how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/RinteRface/bs4Dash/issues/250). You can fix it by adding `skin = "light"` in `dashboardSidebar()`, as below:

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    title = "Basic Dashboard",
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(skin = "light"),
    controlbar = dashboardControlbar(),
    footer = dashboardFooter(),
    body = dashboardBody()
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)
```